# Not able to create site using site template - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have created SharePoint Site, from which I created a site template, now I need to create similar sites under same site collection using the Site Template. In order to automate this functionality I created the Site Template and try to create new sites from this template using SharePoint Designer Workflow using web services.  But while performing this am getting below error.

**"The site template requires that the Feature {bf8b58f5-ebae-4a70-9848-622beaaf2043} be installed in the farm or site collection"**

To troubleshoot this issue I tried to create the site using the same site template manually, which am able to perform successfully.

I found that above GUID **{bf8b58f5-ebae-4a70-9848-622beaaf2043}** refers to Power View feature, which I found activated in my site collection, But am not using any power view related functionality in my application.
I would be grateful, if anyone let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue is with the template. That error is saying before you create the site template, enable that feature at the site level on the template site before saving the site as a template. I had a similar use case about a year ago to automate all our private team site creation. I found this article very useful. 
https://sharepointryan.com/2013/09/10/create-a-sharepoint-site-spweb-using-rest-in-spd-2013-workflow/

In the dictionary for the json request, set WebTemplate to the template / solution ID from your site collection.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped in resolving my issue